# Missing headers linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-686-pae_6.5.6-1kali1_i386.deb

Tags: kali-linux, package-management

Why has `linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-686-pae_6.5.6-1kali1_i386.deb` been taken down? It is not on any of your repositories.

Answer (score 2):

They aren’t our repositories, but that’s not particularly relevant.

Kali only maintains one or two versions of the kernel; currently, that’s 6.6.9-1kali1. See [the `linux` package information](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux) for details.

If you update your system and reboot, you should find you’ll be able to install headers matching your current kernel.